# Unexpted error when accessing pictures

Tags: publishing-site, publishing, blob-cache

Unexpted error when accessing pictures on publishing web. From the ULS log it looks like this is BLOB cache related. The following error message is found for the correlation id:

> 07.08.2011 11:27:57.19    w3wp.exe (0x2984)   0x2BA0  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  Parameter name: utcDate    at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.UtcSetLastModified(DateTime utcDate)     at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.SetLastModified(DateTime date)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.SendCachedFile(HttpContext context, BlobCacheEntry target, SPUserToken currentUserToken, SiteEntry currentSiteEntry)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.SendCachedFile(HttpContext context, BlobCacheEntry target, SiteEntry currentSiteEntry)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.HandleCachedFile(HttpContext context, BlobCacheEntry target, Boolean anonymousUser, SiteEntry currentSiteEntry)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.RewriteUrl(Object sender, EventArgs e, Boolean preAuthenticate)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingHttpModule.AuthorizeRequestHandler(Object sender, EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 74bd2984-794e-4cfd-8069-05b173dfb20b

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the date passed into it is in the future.  This would appear to be the last modified date on one of the pictures held in the library.

I'd try the following:

1. Ensure that all the last modified times on the files in the library are sensible
2. Clear out the blob cache

(Also wondering if you might have some servers in your farm with out of sync clocks?)

Comment: One of the servers were 14 secs out of sync with the others. This was also the server that had the error, so I will mark this as the answer.